# Discontinuous everywhere but range is an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does there exist a function which is discontinuous everywhere but range set is an interval.

Comment: A more extreme example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. We have $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ given by
$$
f(x) =\cases{x& if $x$ is rational \\
x+\frac12& if $x\lt \frac12$ is irrational \\
x-\frac12 & if $x\gt\frac12$ is irrational}
$$
For any $x\in[0,1]$ it's easy to see that $f(x)\in[0,1]$ as well. For any $y\in [0,1]$, we have $f(y) =y$ if $y$ is rational, otherwise $f(y\pm 1/2) =y$, with sign depending on whether $y\gt1/2$ or not. So the unit interval is the range set.

As for discontinuity, let $0<\epsilon <1/2$. Then there is no $\delta$ small enough, no matter what $x$ is, since in any open interval containing $x$ there are both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: A neat bijection

Comment: and self-inverting

Comment: Yes I noticed it also

Answer (score 0):

Define $f:[-1,1]\to[0,1]$ as follows
$$f(x) = x^2 \cdot (\chi_{[-1,0]\cap\mathbb{Q}} + \chi_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{I}})$$
where $\chi_A$ is characteristic function of a set $A$.